# Программа должна суммировать опред. переменные остальное считать за 0,ввод в одной строке без пропусков входные данные:2KTA8JJ59QT76 выходные:11

Tags: python

Бридж — это карточная игра, в которую играют четыре игрока, используя
колоду из 52 карт. Карты бывают четырех мастей и 13 значений. В начале
игры каждый игрок получает 13 карт. Чтобы оценить силу своей руки,
каждый игрок подсчитывает баллы следущим образом
Туз (А) стоит 4 балла
Король (K) оценивается в 3 балла
Дама (Q) стоит 2 балла
Валет (J) стоит 1 балл
Остальные карты стоят 0 баллов.
Вам нужно написать программу, которая по описанию выданных вам 13 карт
посчитает суммарное число баллов.
**Входные данные**
Ввод содержит одну строку из 13 символов.В строке встречаются только
следующие символы: A, K, Q, J, T, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3 и 2. Символы A, K,
Q, J обозначают туза, короля, даму и валета, символ T обозначает
десятку, остальные символы обозначают карты от девятки до двойки,
соответственно.

**Выходные данные**
Выведите одно число — суммарное число баллов.

```py
    v = input()
    A = int(4)
    K = int(3)
    Q = int(2)
    J = int(1)
    h = ['A','K','Q','J']
    b = [A,K,Q,J]
    if v == h:
        x = sum(b)
        print(x) 
    else:
        print(0)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вопрос должен звучать так: "Угадайте алгоритм по моему коду"

Comment: А вопрос-то где? Есть некое положение о проге, есть какой-то код. Сам код выглядит странно. Выдаёт 0, а не 11 (что ожидаемо). Ни v == h, ни x = sum(b) работать правильно не будут. Почитайте про присвоение переменной значения конкретного элемента из списка, а также, как считать накапливаемую сумму. Я бы словарём сделал.  + Python -  c динамической типизацией - int не нужен.

Comment: @СергейШашко, алгоритм в описании + да, часть в начале кода. Он-то угадывается:-)

Comment: Что очевидно для вас, не очевидно для других. Бридж я не играю, но по вашем коду примерно такой алгоритм у себя в уме и норисовал

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на задачу таков:

```py
a = input()
count = 0
for i in a:
    if i == "A":
        count+=4
    elif i == "K":
        count+=3
    elif i == "Q":
        count+=2
    elif i == "J":
        count+=1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

можно в словарь все запихать, создать массив из чисел и просуммировать с помощью `sum`

```py
v = input()
d = {"А": 4, "K": 3, "Q": 2, "J": 1}
print(sum([d[i] for i in v if d.get(i)]))
```